# Pegar valor de um input

Tags: jquery

Tenho dois inputs, e cada input tem uma span.

Segue o código abaixo.

```js
    $('.textInput').on('keyup', function(){
       console.log($(this).val());
      $(".val").attr("date", $('.textInput').val()); 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input class="textInput" type="text" value="teste">
    <span date='' class='val'></span>

    <input class="textInput" type="text" value="teste">
    <span date='' class='val'></span>
```

O **jQuery** pega o valor do input e escreve dentro do atributo date da span. Entretanto ao executar ele está pegando o valor e colocando nas duas span, necessito que ao escrever no input ele escreva na span correspondente ao input.

Comment: Porque o id é único, só pode ser referenciado a um elemento, utilize class, troca id="textInput" para class="textInput"  => $('.textInput').

Comment: É para aparecer o valor do primeiro input em uma span e do outro input na outra span ?? não entendi muito não

Comment: isso se eu digitar no input 2 ele escrever na span 2 se eu escrever no input 1 ele escrever na span 1 do jeito que ta se eu escrevo no input ele escreve nas duas span

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não precisa de id's. O uso excessivo de id's é comum de quem não tem conhecimento mais amplo dos métodos disponibilizados pelo framework. Infla o HTML e deixa o código ruim de trabalhar e manter.

Como cada span é adjacente (vem logo depois) de cada input, utilize o método `.next()` do jQuery. O `.next()` irá selecionar o elemento adjacente ao input digitado (no caso, o `span`):

```js
$('.textInput').on('keyup', function(){
   $(this).next().attr("date", $(this).val());
   // só para exemplo. apague a linha abaixo
   $(this).next().text($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="textInput" type="text" value="teste">
<span date='' class='val'></span>

<input class="textInput" type="text" value="teste">
<span date='' class='val'></span>
```

Comment: @diogo Dsa, isto provavelmente já resolveria sua questão com o formulário "dinâmico" que é implementado em um `foreach` como comentou na resposta do @Joan Marcos.

Comment: obrigado pela explicação comecei a pouco tempo no JQuery tinha feito uma gambiarra
aqui para fazer funcionar com essas quatro linhas de código resolveu todos os problemas.

Comment: Nice mestre, não sabia que existia o método next() :D, Up \o/

Answer (score 4):

Isso ocorre por causa que `id` é referência única a um elemento, logo ele só considera o primeiro elemento criado, mas você pode utilizar `class` que pode ser utilizado para vários elementos.

```
<input class="textInput" type="text" value="teste">

<input class="textInput" type="text" value="teste">

$('.textInput').on('keyup', function(){
   console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Para entender melhor sobre o atributo `id` leia a [documentação da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) e `class` [documentação MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

---

Para setar o valor na sua propriedade `date` ficaria da seguinte forma

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.js"
    integrity="sha256-DYZMCC8HTC+QDr5QNaIcfR7VSPtcISykd+6eSmBW5qo="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="col-xs-4 offset-xs-4">
       <input id="textInput1" class="textInput" type="text" value="teste">
       <span date="" id="date1"></span>

       <input id="textInput2" class="textInput" type="text" value="teste">
       <span date="" id="date2"></span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">

   $('#textInput1').on('keyup', function () {
     console.log('input1 valor: ' + $(this).val());
     $("#date1").attr("date", $('#textInput1').val());
   });

   $('#textInput2').on('keyup', function () {
     console.log('input2 valor: ' + $(this).val());
     $("#date2").attr("date", $('#textInput2').val());
   });

</script>
```

Obs:

> Passei a utilizar o identificador `id` nos elementos já que você quer os
>   valores do elemento específico.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta seu exemplo deu certo para mim eu editei a pergunta poderia rever a resposta

Comment: @diogoDsa está ae man

Comment: obrigado pela resposta percebi que para cada input devo criar um codigo para ele mais como o formulario esta dentro de um foreach pode haver mais de um input pode ter 2 3 4 5 e assim por diante tem alguma forma de criar um for para criar automaticamente

Comment: @diogoDsa mas ae já seria uma outra pegunta man, especificando o que você realmente quer :D

Comment: @diogoDsa se tiver como marca a resposta correta ficaria muito grato :D

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o evento `.keyup()` do jquery chamar a função que pegará os dados, a cada dígito. E utilize a função `.attr("atributo", "valor do atributo")`, para mudar o valor de um elemento HTML.
Exemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.js"
    integrity="sha256-DYZMCC8HTC+QDr5QNaIcfR7VSPtcISykd+6eSmBW5qo="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="col-xs-4 offset-xs-4">
        <input class="textInput form-control" type="text" id="input1">
        <span date='' class='val' id="span1"></span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#input1").keyup(function(){
        $("#span1").attr("date", $(this).val());
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Se inspecionar os elemento verá funcionando!

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta .